# Cómo puedo resetear el valor http.postbuffer

Tags: git, github

Un saludo, podrían ayudarme ya que he introducido un valor para esta variable por error, ya que estaba tratando de dejar el valor que trae esta variable por default y por error he ingresado `"reset"` y esto me está presentando problemas a la hora de clonar un repositorio.

El error es el siguiente:

> fatal: bad numeric config value 'reset' for 'http.postbuffer': invalid unit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplemente configura el `http.postBuffer` con su valor por defecto que es de 1 MiB:

```
$ git config --global http.postBuffer 1024
```

Otra opción es borrar la configuración que has hecho para `http` y dejar que git use el valor por defecto aunque esta opción podría borrar otras configuraciones que hayas hecho en la sección `http`:

```
$ git config --global --remove-section http
```

Acá un ejemplo bastante claro:

```
$ git config --global http.postBuffer "reset"
$ git clone https://github.com/leo-stone/hack-petya.git
Cloning into 'hack-petya'...
fatal: bad numeric config value 'reset' for 'http.postbuffer' in /home/cesar/.gitconfig: invalid unit
$ git config --global http.postBuffer 1024
$ git clone https://github.com/leo-stone/hack-petya.git
Cloning into 'hack-petya'...
remote: Counting objects: 55, done.
remote: Total 55 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 55
Unpacking objects: 100% (55/55), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

### Referencias

- [git-config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias César por tu ayuda, he podido solucionar el problema